# Does VersionCode , VersionName of alpha release affect production release

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

I went through the docs did not see anywhere mentioning on this,
If i release my app for alpha testing or a beta release with version Code 1, name 1.0 does this affect the production release which needs to be Code 1, Name 1.0.

Does the version system get carried over or will production release will have its own version flow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an apk, you must use unique `VersionCode` (integer value) and show to the user the `VersionName` (string value). The PlayStore will not allow you to upload apk with already used `VersionCode`

Comment: i have read this sentence in docs, i need to know if the unique VersionCode is to be unique entirely for a package or is it individually unique for alpha, beta and production releases.

Comment: it's unique for every release (upload to the market). For example, you can start the numbering for your alpha releases from 10000, and increment it, after that you can start the numbering from 20000 for beta releases, from 100000 for actual releases - just make sure to be unique